# sql query to select just one from the pair

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which would hold data for products pairs.

TABLE A

```
ID PAIR1 PAIR2
1   A      B
2   B      A
3   D      M
4   M      D
5   K      T
6   T      K
```

I need to write query that would select A, D, K  (that is one product from each pair) , Even A, M, T is acceptable.

I could think of looping through the whole table.. but want to check if it could be done in single query. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `pair1<pair2` or `pair1>pair2` to get only one pair when there are symmetric pairs.

Comment: oh!! why didnt I think of that :) thank you so much @vkp I can mark it as answer if you put it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select p.*
from products p
where p.id1 < p.id2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the As FullKey to concate

```
select id1 + id2 as FullKey, *

    from products
    where FullKey in (AA','DD','KK')
```